# CKEditor 4 updateElement on blur

Tags: ckeditor

I have a page where I have multiple editors with the class ".ckeditor".

I'm trying to update the values on blur, but blur does not trigger.

```
$(".ckeditor").on("blur", function() {
            console.log("blur");
            for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
                console.log(i);
                CKEDITOR.instances[i].updateElement();// to update the textarea
            }
        });
```

Anyone know if they've totally changed its behaviour in ckeditor 4?

Comment: updateElement has changed. Note: This method will only affect those editor instances created with CKEDITOR.ELEMENT_MODE_REPLACE element mode.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try adding the event in a way like so

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.on('blur', function(e) {
    console.log('onblur fired');
});
```

Comment: Coolness, thanks for the green V. The difference here was that I used CKE's own event model instead of using the underlying element that was used for CKE. CKEditor doesn't actually use the textareas or divs originally used for editing, but rather it replaces them with it's own elaborate system that uses iframes and whatnot so you have to use it's own event model which thankfully is really good. Didn't have time to write that into the answer at the time of posting :)